# Scrollable grid with two rows

Tags: css, flexbox, css-grid

I have a css grid with two rows and multiple columns. I want to "stick the content together".

[How it is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1WXR2.png)

In this way, the grid creates equal-sized columns like this:

[Showing grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iaFxj.png)

But I would like to implement a way in which the columns are independent and the content is "glued", as in the following example.

[Any idea how do that?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lulw0.png)

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  gap: 4px;
  grid-template-rows: auto auto;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

.items {
  width: max-content;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background-color: #F3F4F6;
  padding: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="items">Some text here</div>
  <div class="items">Another text</div>
  <div class="items">More text</div>
  <div class="items">Text here</div>
  <div class="items">Something</div>
  <div class="items">Other thing here</div>
  <div class="items">Here is other</div>
  <div class="items">More text again</div>
  <div class="items">Text really here</div>
  <div class="items">Yes, text</div>
  <div class="items">Texting</div>
  <div class="items">Some text</div>
  <div class="items">Text content</div>
  <div class="items">Text will be here</div>
  <div class="items">Another text here</div>
  <div class="items">Other text</div>
  <div class="items">More text again</div>
  <div class="items">One more text</div>
  <div class="items">Just a text</div>
  <div class="items">The last text</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Looks like inline wrap to me. One possible solution is using row flexbox with flex-wrap instead of grid, but its downside is less control over the two rows structure.

Comment: @CristianSarghe Thanks for the answer. You're right, with flexbox it could work, but I would probably have to manipulate it with javascript to manipulate the two lines. I don't see it any other way. Grid appears to be the way to implement only with CSS, but happens this problem with the positioning of the columns.

Comment: What you are trying to do **is not a grid** so CSS-Grid is not appropriate here.

Answer (score -2):

Try justify-content: space-around;